# Convert a column to an index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df` like this.

```
Number SomeValue SomeOtherValue
  10    10        1.0
  11     3        1.1
```

when I look at the data frame using `df.head()`, I get this

```
  Number SomeValue SomeOtherValue
0  10    10        1.0
1  11     3        1.1
```

I would like `Number` to be my index, so I do something like this:

```
df.index = df.Number
df = df.drop('Number', 1);
```

This seems a bit clumsy, so is there another way of promoting a column to an index?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply use the [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method for this:

```
df.set_index('Number')
```

This take the column out of the DataFrame and sets it as the DataFrame's index. The method also allows you to quickly set multiple columns as indexes or check whether the new index contains duplicates.